# Cannot ping across a bridge (netplan, qemu)

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-bridge, qemu, netplan

I cannot ping a virtual image running as a qemu guest in Ubuntu 18.04.

The default yaml file in `/etc/netplan/` is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
```

I have added another yaml file for the bridge interface as in [this guide](https://netplan.io/examples#bridging):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: true
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses: [ 192.168.56.1/24 ]
      interfaces: [ vlan15 ]
  vlans:
    vlan15:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 15
      link: enp0s25
```

The bridge is created but I cannot ping. Here is the output on the console:

```
PING 192.168.56.7 (192.168.56.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.56.7 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2040ms
pipe 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following configuration working (only one `.yaml` file is used):

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
  eno1:
   dhcp4: yes
   dhcp6: no
  eno2: {}
 bridges:
  br0:
   addresses: [ 192.168.56.7/24 ]
   interfaces: [ vlan15]
 vlans:
  vlan15:
   accept-ra: no
   id: 15
   link: eno2
```